# axis out of bounds with array

Tags: python, arrays, dimension

I have written a code that looks like this.

```
import numpy as np
import math
p0 = np.loadtxt('A.txt', delimiter=',')
p1 = np.loadtxt('B.txt', delimiter=',')
p3 = np.loadtxt('C.txt', delimiter=',')
p = np.loadtxt('D.txt', delimiter=',')
d = 3
def distvec(p0,p1,p3,p,d):
    vec=[]
    for j in range(d):
        p0 = p0[j]
        p1 = p1[j]
        p3 = p3[j]
        p =  p[j]
        u = p0 - p3
        v = p1 - p3
        n = np.cross(u, v)
        norm = math.sqrt(np.dot(n,n))**(-1)
        n=n*norm
        p_ = p - p0
        dist_to_plane = np.dot(p_, n)
        dist=math.sqrt(dist_to_plane**2)
        vec=vec+[dist]
    return vec
distvec(p0,p1,p3,p,d)
```

The text files look something like this.

A.txt

```
23.172,-20.751,31.982
23.049,-20.789,32.164
22.914,-20.952,32.14
```

B.txt

```
21.879,-17.819,34.467
21.727,-17.975,34.311
21.804,-18.267,34.462
```

C.txt

```
20.273,-20.379,34.271
20.144,-20.614,34.36
20.065,-20.765,34.408
```

D.txt

```
21.936,-19.639,33.555
21.771,-19.7,33.506
21.581,-19.955,33.543
```

However, I have been getting an error message that says

File "test.py", line 25, in 
    distvec(p0,p1,p3,p,d)
  File "test.py", line 17, in distvec
    n = np.cross(u, v)
  File "/Users/Sam/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1709, in cross
    axisa = normalize_axis_index(axisa, a.ndim, msg_prefix='axisa')
numpy.core._internal.AxisError: axisa: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

Does anyone know what went wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.cross(u, v)` returns the cross product of two vectors. In your case, `u` and `v` are not vectors but scalars which have dimension 0. This is because you are having `u = p0 - p3` where `p0` and `p3` are `j`th element of your array (`p0 = p0[j]`).

To verify, you can print `u` and `v` and check if they are scalars or a 1-d array (vectors).

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I get your answer. I replaced p0 with p0a, p1 with p1a in the for loop and it works now :)